# ¿Como puedo obtener el texto de un Query?

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando con un sistema que hace consultas a base de datos, no tengo problema con armar la consulta ni tampoco con que me regrese la información.

Pero requiero imprimir en un `log` con `Logger` todas las consultas que hago.

Este es el texto que tengo:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(Queries.queryLoginUser);
query.setParameter(1, UtilDate.format());
query.setParameter(2, UtilDate.formatF("2020-02-02"));
myLogger.info("Ejecutando : " + query.toString());
```

La idea sería que en lugar de poner `query.toString()` pueda poner algo para que me regrese la consulta `sql` ya con los parametros cambiados

Answer (score 1):

Pues al final no pude imprimir mi query tal como quería lo que hice fue crear una función que me armara el string en vez de usar setParameter e imprimí después de crearlo

La función que utilicé fue la siguiente

```
public static String CambiaParamtroQuery(String query, String data) {
    return query.replaceFirst("XX", data);
}
```

Y su uso seria algo así

```
String query = "Select * from tabla where parametro = XX";

query = (query, variable);
```

Comment: Considera publicar la respuesta de lo que lograste realizar para que en caso que alguien tenga el mismo problema, se base en tu solución

Comment: Es excelente que respondas tu propia pregunta, sin embargo, en su forma actual la respuesta es de muy baja calidad. Por favor lee [answer]. Sugiero que añadas un pequeño ejemplo de cómo lo resolviste. Un saludo.